# Prefilter bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView with URL parameters

Tags: yii, yii-booster

Is it possible to predefine a filter in TbGridView trough URL parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by prefilling the attribute in your model. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10551681/2329962) for an example.